# RabbitMQ on Windows 10 - unable to connect to epmd: adress (cannot connect to host/port)

Tags: rabbitmq, epmd

I've been unsuccessfully struggling to get RabbitMQ working again on my machine for some time. It was installed and working then something went wrong. I've uninstalled and then installed v3.8.0 (with Erlang version 22).

I've run `rabbitmq-service.bat start` and the service starts successfully, but when I run `rabbitmqctl.bat list_users` I get the following error:

```
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@<my hostname>'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@<my hostname>
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@<my hostname>]

rabbit@<my hostname>:
  * unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on [My host name here]: address (cannot connect to host/port)


Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-7856-rabbit@<my hostname>'
 * effective user's home directory: C:\Users\<myusername>
 * Erlang cookie hash: hXRZg8Foj+FXs7DwcLF6cg==
```

I'm running it locally and it has been working before.

I've checked the `.erlang.cookie` and they're correct.

I've run the `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management` command to enable the management plugin but cannot connect to the management UI.

Comment: Is `epmd.exe` running? Is port `4369` open (not blocked by your firewall)?

Comment: @LukeBakken `epmd.exe` is running and as far as I can tell port `4369` is open and listening

Comment: Does `my hostname` resolve as expected? Can you run `telnet my_hostname 4369` and connect successfully? If you don't have `telnet` you can install it or another tool like `netcat`. You're just testing that a connection to port 4369 using the expected hostname `my_hostname` actually works.

Comment: @LukeBakken I can telnet successfully to port 4369 on my host without issue.

Comment: @LukeBakken this is all on my localhost, but I don't want my corporate machine name in my post, hence my use of `my_hostname`.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I run RabbitMQ on Windows all the time and have never seen it. Try stopping the service, ensuring that all `epmd.exe` processes are gone, and re-starting. Ensure you don't have multiple Erlang versions in `C:\Program Files\erl*`

Comment: Perhaps worth going for the latest RabbitMQ Release and the Latest ErLang Runtime..

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee this is the latest RMQ release and the version of Erlang specified by them.

Comment: @LukeBakken what's most frustrating is that this was working last week!

Comment: Looks purely an environment issue , try setting it up on a fresh box if works fine then probably some file has got screwed up .. you know how Windows behave.

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee it has to be on this specific machine unfortunately. I agree it's likely to be an environment issue since it's working fine elsewhere, but I have to get it working in this location.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/3C739Frn6AE/discussion

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and the only way I could resolve it was to

1. completely uninstall rabbitmq and erl OTP,
2. clear out the .erlang.cookie files
   from c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile and c:\users\username
3. delete the erl and rabbitmq folders from Program Files
4. then reinstall
   everything from the ground up.

Once I did that, I used the following commands in an ADMINISTRATOR cmd

> rabbitmq-service remove
>
> rabbitmq-service install
>
> rabbitmq-service start

And then I got a different error about authentication failed. I then copied the .erlang.cookie from the windows folder to my user folder and tried again and it worked.